# Equivalent to "CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0,0)" when using Auto Layout? To animate back to original position

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to animate a view from position A to B and then back again. Previously, I would do something like the following to animate to B:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 0);
}];
```

And then this to animate back to A:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
}];
```

All without needing to know the original position.

Now in Auto Layout I am using the following code to animate to position B:

```
self.myLeadingConstraint.constant = 100;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Is there a way to get the previous constant value without needing to create another variable or look in IB to see what the initial value is? 
Is there a better way to do all of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a quick note, don't use `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)`, instead use `CGAffineTransformIdentity`, it's a constant made specially for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's the simplest way. Here are your options to animate autolayout:

- Call layoutIfNeeded in a block. If you are just translating, change only the constant.
- Animate layers instead of views.
- Drop constraints, use autosizing masks.
- Use a container view and animate that container.
- Use constraints that don’t interfere.
- Set frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

What you mean getting the previous constant value? isn't that on self.myLeadingConstraint.constant already?